# Does tensorflow-federated support placing training data on client side?

Tags: tensorflow-federated, remote-execution

It's very awesome to see that tensorflow-federated could support distributed training now. I referred to the example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/high_performance_simulation_with_kubernetes.ipynb). 
However, it seems the training data are sent from server to client at each epoch, and the client(remote_executor_service) doesn't hold any dataset. It is different from typical federated learning scenario. So I was wondering could I place training data separately on each client?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note:

- The example linked ([High-performance Simulation with Kubernetes](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/high_performance_simulation_with_kubernetes.ipynb)) is running a federated learning *simulation*. At this time TensorFlow Federated is primarily used for executing research simulations. There has yet to be a means for deploying to real smart phones. In the simulation, each client dataset is *logically* separate, but may be *physically* present on the same machine.
- The creation of a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) (e.g. the definition of `train_data` in the tutorial) could be thought of like creating a "recipe to read data", than actually reading the data itself. For example, adding `.batch()` or `.map()` calls to a dataset returns a new recipes, but doesn't actually materialize any dataset examples. The dataset isn't actually read until a `.reduce()` call, or the dataset is iterated over in a `for` loop. In the tutorial, the dataset "recipe" is sent to remote workers; the data is read/materialized remotely when the dataset is iterated over during local training (the data itself is not sent to the remote workers).